# Getting wide character string from /dev/urandom on linux

Tags: c, linux, string, random, wchar

I'm trying to get a wide character string from `/dev/urandom` but there is nothing or some short strange results on `STDOUT`. I need to solve this problem today. Please help me! What's wrong with it...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t text[100];
    FILE *urandom;
    int x = 5;

    urandom = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");

    while(x--){

        fgetws(text, 100, urandom);
        fwprintf(stdout, L"%ls\n", text);
        //fputws(text, stdout);

    }

    fclose(urandom);

    return 0;

}
```

**EDIT:**

[THIS IS WHAT I SHOULD GET](http://scr.hu/0w7rd/4kxul) (using `normal char[], fgets, fputs`):

[THIS IS WHAT I'M GETTING](http://scr.hu/0w7rd/jfxgb) (using `wchar_t[], fgetws, fwprintf/fputws`):

Comment: please include expected output and current output in your problem description. Good luck.

Comment: If I don't do `#include <locale.h>`, I have no results, however, if I do, I get a string of 100 same characters.

Comment: What makes you think that any random garbage is going to encode a valid wide character?

Comment: It's random, any result should be correct...

Comment: Post edited. I put two links as an example of OUTPUT.

Comment: Random bytes does not make valid strings. Most Linux users currently use an UTF-8 locale. If you read e.g. bytes 65, 129, and 128, they do not encode into a valid string (because 129 is not a valid value for an UTF-8 character sequence). Similarly, reading random numbers as integers does not valid wide character strings make. Instead, read integers (perhaps `wchar_t`'s), and use e.g. [`iswprint()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iswprint.3.html) to test whether it is a valid (printable) character. This kind of *exclusion method* is common when working with random numbers.